# OpenERP field to hold time values such as `08:04`

Tags: python, datetime, field, odoo

i'm working in a module openeRP

i'm looking for a solution to declare a field in which i can add a time like this: `08:04`.

i found this type `datetime` but it's not what i need.

```
fields.datetime
```

it doesn't work

because i don't need a date i need only the time.

can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use the `float_time` widget

I'm not sure whether you actually need to store a *time* or a *duration*. If you want to store a duration, the easiest is probably to use a `fields.float` in combination with `float_time` widget. This is what OpenERP uses by default for storing task durations.

This will store the value in hours as a float in the database, but lets the users see and enter values using the familiar HH:MM format. So if the user enters `8:30` the value stored in the database will be `8.5`. Having float values for durations makes it very easy to compute sums or average durations across many records.

For example your OpenERP model could have the following:

```
_columns: {
    'duration': fields.float('Duration (in hours)'),
}
```

and the corresponding view would contain:

```
<field name="duration" widget="float_time"/>
```

You can see a similar example in the official `project` module, at [model](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0/view/8790/project/project.py#L759) and [view](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0/view/8790/project/project_view.xml#L141) levels.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try  `fields.time`. I dont know openerp still have this field.

Comment: It's been removed in v7.0.